# Specifying DNS server for lookup in Go

Tags: go, dns

Is there a way to specify which DNS server to use for a name lookup?

Looking at https://golang.org/pkg/net/#LookupHost seems it will use only the local resolver

```
LookupHost looks up the given host using the local resolver. It returns a slice 
of that host's addresses.
```

Also earlier on that link

```
 It can use a pure Go resolver that sends DNS requests directly to 
 the servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf,
```

How could one do a lookup against arbitrary servers like one can do with dig?

```
dig @8.8.8.8 google.com
```

Answer (score 36):

Answer from [/u/g-a-c](https://www.reddit.com/user/g-a-c) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/esus2j/specifying_dns_server_for_lookup/)

If I'm reading that doc right (maybe not)...

Create yourself a local Resolver, with a custom Dialer, using the DNS address you want to use (https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Resolver) then use the LookupAddr function of that Resolver?

edit:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    r := &net.Resolver{
        PreferGo: true,
        Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
            d := net.Dialer{
                Timeout: time.Millisecond * time.Duration(10000),
            }
            return d.DialContext(ctx, network, "8.8.8.8:53")
        },
    }
    ip, _ := r.LookupHost(context.Background(), "www.google.com")

    print(ip[0])
}
```

This seems to work - on my firewall this shows that my machine is opening connections to Google rather than a local domain controller

Comment: With the caveat that the DNS uses UDP **AND** TCP. The above may not give you answers for queries whose answer wouldn't fit an UDP packet.

Comment: This is a nice example. I weaked it so invocations for TCP will call DialContext with the passed 'network' flags. Nonetheless, even when I caused UDP based call backs to return an error, the pureGo-resolver never called 'Dial' with a network of TCP. HERE is the crazy part! You can still pass "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6" to DialContext and the resolver will use a TCP transport rather than a UDP transport. Confirmed with Wireshark.

Comment: In my case, unfortunately, the code above returns the private IP of my external POP, as if it still queried the internal DNS (go 1.16)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek can you explain further please? Is there a place I can learn more about this?

Comment: @nc. The answer was edited after my comment. It had initially `return d.DialContext(ctx, "udp", "8.8.8.8:53")` which has the problem described in my comment. The edit done says even with `network` there might be a problem (no fallback to TCP). So in all cases, whatever you do, as a DNS client you need to try both UDP and TCP and be smart about it. UDP replies may not come or come with Truncated flag in DNS packet answer, in which cases you need to retry with TCP. You have also the `bufsize` EDNS0 option for UDP which can help or not.

Comment: @nc. Where to learn what precisely? About DNS stuff, the core documents are RFC 1034 and 1035 but they are old, terse, with errors, multiple times updated by other documents, etc. so quite complicated. The page at https://powerdns.org/hello-dns/ might be a better introduction on the technical points. Otherwise questions here (if related to programming), [webmasters.se] for DNS related to the web, or serverfault.com for administration/use of DNS servers in business settings are ways to learn.

Comment: And don't forget the port 53 at the end of your IP. Otherwise, it'll work but ip will be empty.

Comment: Isn't setting the `PreferGo` to `true` and using Google's DNS resolver (`8.8.8.8`) conflicting? Which one will be used at the end of the day?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this method to allow custom DNS server querying.

However, I'm noticing that it is considerably slower to perform DNS lookups when a customer resolver is used.

When I use the default net resolver the querying time for 9 DNS records is 200ms, but when f.x 8.8.8.8 is used then the querying time for 9 DNS records is 1600 ms.

This also scales linearly, so the more DNS records queried the larger the gap in ms

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30856516)